# Pandas: delete consecutive duplicates but keep the first and last value

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a set of values in a column that looks like this:

```
1 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 4
```

I'm trying to delete the repeating zeros but keep the first and last ones. 
End result should look like this:

`1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 4`

*Drop duplicates* won't work because it deletes all the zeros, not independent consecutive zeros.

```
df = df.loc[df.people.shift() != df.people]
```

this works well but does not save the last number of that consecutive one

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `fillna` with `limit`

```
s[s.replace(0,np.nan).ffill(limit=1).bfill(limit=1).notnull()]
Out[387]: 
0     1
1     0
2     2
3     1
4     1
5     0
9     0
10    1
11    2
12    0
15    0
16    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this but with all types of values - not just zeros?

Comment: @boboT just replace the value to np.nan and you can get the result

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***

```
s = pd.Series([1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4])
```

You can make use of boolean indexing based on **`shift`** to check if an element is zero, and also check that it is in the middle of a group of zeros, while not being the first or last zero.

```
s[~((s==0) & (s == s.shift(1)) & (s == s.shift(-1)))]
```

Output:

```
0     1
1     0
2     2
3     1
4     1
5     0
9     0
10    1
11    2
12    0
15    0
16    4
dtype: int64
```